# Impossible create Test plan using RQL Expression (Allure EE)

Tags: allure

At Allure EE tool I would like to create Test plan using RQL Expression.
Our project has a lot of test case with different tag (i.e @regress). And I want to fill the test plan with test cases which tagged '@regress'.
I enter tags = '@regress' in Base filter field, but 'invalid query' error appears every time.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pvV5e.png)

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 problems with your query:

1. There is no `tags` attribute available. You should use `tag` instead.
2. Allure expects string literals be surrounded with double quotes.

So the following query will work as expected: `tag = "@regress"`

See the docs for more details: https://docs.qameta.io/allure-ee/query-language/test-cases/